# Backup group's repositories from gitlab.com

Tags: automation, backup, gitlab

I'd like to automate a weekly backup of all of my group's repos (hosted at [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com))

I was wondering is there a better way than creating a script that will use the API iterate thorough all the group's repos, clone each and then upload the files to a cold storage?

Answer (score 1):

Using the public gitlab.com site, you are correct, you really can only write your own shell script to clone the repos you want to make an offline copy of.

If you were on a private gitlab, you would use gitlab's built in backup tools. The resulting backup can be restored onto a fresh Gitlab instance and will restore everything for you.

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#create-a-backup-of-the-gitlab-system :

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

These backups can get very large if you have CI artifacts. I like to skip them, with this command:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=artifacts
```

These backups go into the backup directory you configured in `/etc/gitlab.rb`

As you are using a public site (gitlab.com), you might want to consider setting up a Private Gitlab instance so you can have your own hosted solution that is local, can be backed up using Gitlab's own tooling, etc. You can also then set up your own runners, and all kinds of other things that you can't do on gitlab.com.

Git is a DVCS, and your local working repo clones ARE a full backup of your Code ONLY, not your issues, or your wiki.

My entire reason for being a huge fan of Gitlab is because it lets me host my own git server. Gitlab.com is useful for me, because I keep some stuff up there for other people to see publically, but my primary professional work is always on my own private gitlabs, which have my own DR stuff.  Paddle your own canoe, run your OWN gitlab.